# Set retention period for Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set the retention period on a kafka topic to 1000 ms to delete the unwanted messages on it.
I've used

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper my-zookeeper:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name my_logger --add-config retention.ms=1000,segment.bytes=14
```

The command works fine, I can see the new value when I describe the topic, but the messages are not removed from the topic, when I check it using

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server my-bootstrap-server --group my-connector --describe
```

I can see thet the **LAG** value is still the same and it dosen't change.

I'm doing something wrong here? How can I trigger the retention period?

Kafka version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You should also change **log.roll.ms**.

**log.roll.ms**:  every partition is divided into segment logs (log.segment.bytes).
This configuration controls the period of time after which Kafka will force the log to roll even if the segment file isn’t full to ensure that retention can delete or compact old data. A new log segment is rolled out by default every 7 days.

But please note that you should change these configs after the messages deletion because small segments can lead to serious performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Deletion of a Message from Kafka is much more complicated than it appears to be. Following blog gives glimpse of various factors affecting the deletion of a message from Kafka.

[Understanding Kafka's Internal Storage and Log Retention](https://www.conduktor.io/blog/understanding-kafkas-internal-storage-and-log-retention/)